# Fetch information from DBPedia service

Tags: c#, json, parsing, sparql, dbpedia

I am able to get a JSON version of dbpedia resource as below :
http://dbpedia.org/data/Influenza.json

But I am not able to parse it and pull desired result, Abstract and ICD code using JSON to Object method.

[image]

Also not sure how to develop a query to pull the same information using SPARQL query.

Any suggestion on how to get this will be helpful.

Comment: did you check any SPARQL tutorial or the SPARQL specs? Either a very simple `SELECT` query or a `CONSTRUCT` would do the trick. Or just use `DESCRIBE <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Influenza>` (don't forget to gather incoming triples as shown on the DBpedia pages quite often)

Comment: And media type must be `application/rdf+json`

Comment: Thanks, I will try now.

Comment: If you just need the 3 properties as in the screenshot, indeed, you should use a `SELECT ... WHERE {...}` query.

Comment: I am going through the tutorial and it is not very easy for me to relate these. I just abstract and ICD code from it. Can you please give me some hint on how to query this, I can easily integrate SPARQL query from .Net program.

Comment: You already made it by yourself :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ?abstract ?icd10 ?icd9 
WHERE { 
    [ rdfs:label ?name; 
    dbo:abstract ?abstract; 
    dbo:icd10 ?icd10; 
    dbo:icd9 ?icd9 ]
.FILTER langMatches(lang(?abstract),'en') 
VALUES ?name {  'Urinary incontinence' @en } }
```

This seems to be giving me the desired result.

Comment: You see, not that difficult. Well done in a very short time! Don't forget to "accept" your own answer!

Comment: Minor comment, the commas between the projection variables are non-standard SPARQL just provided by Virtuoso triple store which is the backend of DBpedia. Other triple stores and SPARQL APIs might fail during parsing. And `DISTINCT` isn't needed in this query

Comment: Thanks for the help @AKSW I am now facing some issue with querying it from .net. Will open a new question on that.

Comment: @AKSW - I am stuck again on adding OPTIONAL for ICD10 And ICD9 columns.. Any idea how to put that..so that I dont get issue with missing values

Comment: sure, in that case you have to use a less compact version like you did with the blank node `[ ... ]` and give the subjects of the triple patterns a name, e.g. `?s` , resulting in something like `SELECT ?abstract ?icd10 ?icd9 
WHERE { 
VALUES ?name {  'Urinary incontinence'@en }
    ?s rdfs:label ?name; 
    dbo:abstract ?abstract
FILTER langMatches(lang(?abstract),'en')
FILTER langMatches(lang(?name),'en')  

    optional{?s dbo:icd10 ?icd10 } 
    optional {?s dbo:icd9 ?icd9 }
 }`